# how to output the contents of the list

Tags: c#

essentially I'm making a guessing game for an assignment but as I try to output the list it comes out as

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]

essentially I just need to store a users guess number and their attempt number so that once they guess the correct number it will display it as

"YOU WON, the number was ___ and here are your attempts

1. you chose 45
2. you chose 54
3. you chose 32
4. you chose ___

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace main__4_8_2021_
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            while (true)
                try
                {
                    int NumberOfTries = 0;
                    Console.WriteLine("Guess a number between 1 and 100");
                    int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    List<int> mylist2 = new List<int>(number);
                    List<int> mylist = new List<int>(NumberOfTries);

                    int rng = new Random().Next(1, 101);

                    if (number == rng)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Your guess was correct! The number was " + number + "!");
                            Console.WriteLine(mylist);
                            Console.WriteLine(mylist2);
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (number > rng)
                        {
                            NumberOfTries++;
                            Console.WriteLine("Your guess was too high ");
                            Console.WriteLine(mylist);
                            Console.WriteLine(mylist2);
                            Console.WriteLine("you now have done " + NumberOfTries + " Tries");
                        }
                        else if (number < rng)
                        {
                            NumberOfTries++;
                            Console.WriteLine("too low, ");
                            Console.WriteLine(mylist);
                            Console.WriteLine(mylist2);
                            Console.WriteLine("you now have done " + NumberOfTries + " Tries");
                        }

                        Console.Write($"Try again. ");
                }

                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

(the other console.writelines of the lists are just there for debug)

Comment: One way is to use string.Join, e.g. `string.Join(",", mylist )`. if you want to format the value use LINQ and string interpolation too, e.g. `string.Join(",", mylist.Select(x => $"... {x} ..."))`

Comment: Your question seems to be [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of issues with your code.

First, you don't need a counter for number of attempts, a `Count` property on the `List` is enough.

Second, you need to keep that list outside of the loop so it is not recreated each time.

Try the below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace main__4_8_2021_
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> mylist = new List<int>();
            void PrintListContents() {
                   Console.WriteLine("here are your attempts");
                   var index = 0;
                   foreach(var value in mylist) {
                       Console.WriteLine($"{index}. You chose {value}");
                       index++;
                   }
            }


            while (true)
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Guess a number between 1 and 100");
                    int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    mylist.Add(number);
                    int rng = new Random().Next(1, 101);

                    if (number == rng)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Your guess was correct! The number was " + number + "!");
                            PrintListContents()
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (number > rng)
                        {
                            NumberOfTries++;
                            Console.WriteLine("Your guess was too high ");
                            PrintListContents()                            
                            Console.WriteLine("you now have done " + myList.Count + " Tries");
                        }
                        else if (number < rng)
                        {
                            NumberOfTries++;
                            Console.WriteLine("too low, ");
                            PrintListContents()                            
                            Console.WriteLine("you now have done " + myList.Count + " Tries");
                        }

                        Console.Write($"Try again. ");
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine(mylist);
```

> If value is null, only the line terminator is written. Otherwise, the
> ToString method of value is called to produce its string
> representation, and the resulting string is written to the standard
> output stream.
>
> SOURCE https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-5.0#System_Console_WriteLine_System_Object_

this means that you actually calling the `ToString` method of the list. Most of the "complex" types do not overwrite the `ToString` method which results in just returning the  string representation of `Type`. In your case: `List<int>` which is represented as System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]

you may also want to have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-5.0